# Using DMA to read every second Byte from DCMI only

Tags: c++, camera, stm32, dma

I am currently using the STM32F4 Discovery Board and the OV7670 Camera.
Using the DCMI and DMA on the Discovery Board I managed to get pictures.

The camera is set to YCbCr422 mode (so 4 bytes for 2 pixels) but in the end I only extract the Y byte from it to receive a **grayscale/monochrome** image.

My problem is this:
Due to the limited RAM on the Discovery Board I only managed to get images in QCIF resolution (176 x 144).

The Discovery Board hast 192K of SRAM which is distributed to 3 blocks : 112KB + 16KB + 64KB.
So largest contiguos block is 112 KB.

I estimated the following memory needs (in Byte) for the different camera resolutions:

- **QCIF 160x121:** 
  RAM USED: 
  4 Bytes 2 Pixel: 38720 - Grayscale only : 19360
- **QVGA 320x240:**
  RAM USED:
  4 Bytes 2 Pixel: 153600 - Grayscale only: 76800
- **VGA 640x480:**
  RAM USED:
  4 Bytes 2 Pixel: 614400 - Grayscale only : 307200

So VGA is just not possible.
When using 4 Bytes for 2 Pixels only QCIF fits in the first RAM block. However, if only the Grayscale Byte could be used, the QVGA would fit in as well!

I didn't find a mode for the camera to output grayscale images only. So I need to find another way to do it (if possible).

So the DCMI always reads 4 Bytes, which correspond to the YUV values: Y0, Cb, Y1, Cr

The DMA stores those in my memory and increments after every step. I'd only need every second Byte of the DCMI, so is there any way to tell the DMA to only read every second byte?
This would solve my issue. But I'm not sure how to to this.

Is there maybe another way?
Any suggestions are very welcome!

Kind regards

Comment: What you need and what is efficient are separate issues.  DMA controllers are very good at transferring blocks of sequential data (not skipping).  Skipping or ignoring bytes may take more intelligence in the DMA chip and thus lower the efficiency and speed of the data transfer.  I recommend transferring all the data and incrementing your pointer by 2 to get every second byte.

Comment: Thank you for your input regarding DMA controllers and skipping. But by transferring all data to memory (what I am doing now) I can not store any image with resolution higher than QCIF, because the DMA will transfer the whole image to memory (RAM) first. Or did I misunderstand you? How can I increment my pointer by 2 to get every second byte only into RAM? I am not exactly sure what you mean by this..

Comment: The pointer is for after the data is in memory.  Access every other byte by incrementing the pointer by 2.  Unless the DMA chip you are referring to has the features you need, you may have to perform multiple transfers.

Comment: I am still not sure whether I understood you right. My problem is that I can not get all the data (one whole picture) to memory (only for QCIF, but I need QVGA!). I think my DMA is not capable of performing what I need (Byte skipping). Another idea I had was using a second DMA which is connected to the DCMI and instead of reading a whole WORD from the DCMI I set each DMA to read only one byte, like so: First DMA reads the first byte of DCMI, and the second DMA reads the third byte in the DMA. But I could not get it to work so far.. would that at least even work in theory?

Comment: @thomas - there is insufficient RAM to do that as the OP pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

@robo With an 8 bit interface I don't think you will do it with a single DMA as you point out.

```
Set your HDMI DMA to bring data into a short buffer (say 1K)
Set interrupts for half and full buffer
Use mem->mem DMA to transfer alternate bytes to your final buffer
m->m is set to word in, byte out
```

Probably better to get rid of the unnecessary data before it hits your CPU

```
 Run 2 shift registers (SRa and SRb) connected by 8 bits in parallel
 SRa  is a SIPO  SRB is a PISO (SIPO = Serial in , Parallel out)
 Clock SRa at the incoming bitspeed
 Clock SRb at half the speed
 Latch the data from SRa to SRb once every 16 bit times
 SRb feeds the 8 bits you want to the DMA
```

All this can be managed by timers and GPIO on your CPU.

You select which byte by timing the transfer strobe.

Two 74xx595 series device will do the trick, just check the speed rating. It'll cost about $1. A bit of external hardware is often required in embedded, though this is decreasing each year and to be avoided.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I like the idea. Unfortunately, the dcmi I'm using  is connected to the camera via an 8 bit bus, and it reads 4 bytes after generating an interrupt. And btw actually I don't need video, I just need to be able to take one, or several pictures at a higher resolution. But yes basically the problem stays the same I think

Comment: If I had one interrupt every 16 bits it would work, but I'm not sure if I can set up the dcmi to do so.. Now what I I'm getting is 1 interrupt every 4 bytes, so that's why I thought maybe using 2 DMAs will do but apparently it doesn't work for some reason..

Answer (score 1):

**First way with DCMI**

Configure DMA for circular receive by 4 bytes. Each DMA TC irq copy second byte from DMA buffer to other big buffer.

**Second way without DCMI**

You can receive receive bytes from data port by VSYNC, HSYNC and HREF signals, so you can trigger timer by HREF signal with PSC=1 and by compare event (must be configured for correspont to second byte) from any channel turn DMA to receive one byte. Timer must be enabled by VSYNC signal for fit compare event with byte order.

**Conclusion**

I'm prefer for second way because it will be more effective for power save.